# Will the deprecated /clr:oldSyntax supported in VS2005 and VS2008 still work with VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2010, clr

Does anyone know (with confidence either way) if Microsoft plans on continued support (as in compiling) the legacy (2003) deprecated (vs2005/vs2008) Managed C++ (MC++) Syntax to target the .NET CLR in C++ code?

Microsoft officially deprecated the /clr:oldSyntax with the VS2005 C++ Compiler (Orcas); and thankfully the VS2008 C++ compiler still supported the /clr:oldSyntax switch.

But will the C++ Compiler with VS2010 still support it?  Or will the release of VS2010 finally break the backward compatibility with the /clr:oldSyntax?

I need to know before VS2010 is released for project planning scheduling and can't find the official word on the MSDN site or MVP sites?

Comment: They finally removed this flag with Visual Studio 2015:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2967191.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be supported - see VS2010 beta 2 [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8d11d4s(VS.100).aspx) for `/clr`.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't find the information on MSDN or MVP, then it's probably a good idea to ask Microsoft directly [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/categories/) (the C++ ones, I'd guess). I don't work for Microsoft but I do work for another (very) large organization and we developers monitor public fora very closely. I suspect there's quite a few MS developers who would be watching that site.

However, if you're doing project planning without risk management and contingencies, you're not doing it right.

You should allow for the possibility that it will *not* be supported and do one of two things.

- have an item in your Gantt chart to allow for the re-engineering.
- have a risk log that clearly states re-engineering may be necessary.

From my experience, the first is usually better since, if you find you don't have to do it and the schedule is slipping, you can just drop that item to catch up. Sometimes you can drop it anyway and deliver sooner, just to make yourself look better for your annual performance review :-)

But even if you don't allow for it and then find it's necessary, the risk morphs into an issue and you can go to higher management to explain why more time is needed. You're covered since it was made clear in the risk log - it then becomes their decision to allow you more time or keep using a back-level of MSVC.

Keep in mind that if you don't have to do it, you probably still should consider it (sans schedule slippage). Microsoft didn't deprecate them for a laugh, they're going to disappear at some point. Although YAGNI suggests you shouldn't worry about it unless it's imminent, it would be prudent to do *some* work on getting ready for it.

That will avoid the last-minute mad rush when Microsoft finally do remove the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can check out the [CTP bits](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/content/content.aspx?ContentID=9790).  That's not a guarantee of what will be final, but it's a good idea.  Doubtful there will be any big compiler changes at this point.